# RxJS operators execution order

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Considering I have the following code:

```js
private readonly postAction$ = new Subject();

postStream$ = this.postAction$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => {
      this.count ++;
      console.log('fired')
      return of('my other post');
    }),
    startWith(''),
    exhaustMap(()=> {
      this.count ++;
      console.log('fired first')
      return of('my post' + this.count);
    })
  )
```

Which I subscribe to in my template using the `async` pipe.

I wasn't expecting this to work, but the output to the console was:

```
> fired first
```

Until I call `.next()` on the `postAction$` subject, the first `console.log('fired')` is never called.

What's the execution context of RxJS operators? How do they work? I would have expected that the first exhaust map needed to emit a value, before the rest of the operators are ran. Couldn't find anything in the rxjs [docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators)

Demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-action-stream-mm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to find the answer is to actually see what's going on behind the scenes(I haven't done that, but I hope to do so in the future).

Until then, here is how I see things.

Think of a **stream** as **river**.
The river is traversed by **boats**, which basically are the **emitted values**.
There are also **bridges**, you can think of them as **operators**. Each bridge might require **some conditions** in order to decide which boat can continue its way and which not.

Here is how I'd visualize it:

```js
            The value from `startWith`
                     ↓
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~|~~~B~~~~|~~~~~~~~

        ^        ^        ^
        |        |    `exhaustMap(() => {})`
        |        |
        |   `startWith('B')`
        |
`exhaustMap(() => {})`
```

The `async` pipe internally subscribes to(and unsubscribes from) the given observable. I think of the subscription as the process of setting up the **river**, and the **bridges**. There are no boats yet.
But, in this case, a **boat** can **start from the second bridge**, which means that the first one will have nothing to say about this.

This, if you place the bridges this way:

```js
 postStream$ = this.postAction$.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    exhaustMap(() => {
      this.count ++;
      console.log('fired')
      return of('my other post');
    }),
    exhaustMap(()=> {
      this.count ++;
      console.log('fired first')
      return of('my post' + this.count);
    })
  )
```

You should see this output in the console:

```
fired
fired first
```